# Get output of subprocess without garbage

Tags: python, subprocess, transcrypt

In the [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org) Python to JavaScript compiler,
I use the following code to pipe data through a subprocess:

```
                process = subprocess.Popen (
                    [node.args [1] .s],
                    shell = True,
                    stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdout = subprocess.PIPE
                )
                process.stdin.write (sourceCode.encode ('utf8'))
                process.stdin.close ()
                while process.returncode is None:
                    process.poll ()
                targetCode = process.stdout.read (). decode ('utf8'). replace ('\r\n', '\n')
```

My subprocess is a Windows .bat file containing:

```
python capitalize.py
```

The contents of capitalize.py are:

```
import sys
content = sys.stdin.read ()
sys.stdout.write (content.upper ())
```

If variable `sourceCode` initially contains:

```
dit
is
een
test
```

as a result variable `targetCode` will contain:

```
    D:\activ_tosh\geatec\transcrypt\qquick\Transcrypt\transcrypt\development\experiments\pipe>python capitalize.py 

    D:\activ_tosh\geatec\transcrypt\qquick\Transcrypt\transcrypt\development\experiments\pipe>call D:\python36_anaconda\python.exe capitalize.py 

        DIT
        IS
        EEN
        TEST
```

In other words, the echo of the commands is prepended to stdout, as can be expected.

If I start the command file with `echo off`, that gets echoed, so it doesn't help.

How can I change the code of subprocess.Popen  (or code surrounding it) such that `targetCode` will only contain:

```
        DIT
        IS
        EEN
        TEST
```

I've tried many things, including use of `echo off` in various places and reassigning stdout. And I've been Googling quite a lot, but found no solution. Anyone knows how to solve this?

[EDIT1]
@Mahesh Karia

I've tried:

```
                process = subprocess.Popen (
                    [node.args [1] .s],
                    shell = True,
                    stdout = subprocess.PIPE
                )
                print (111)
                targetCode = process.communicate (io.StringIO (sourceCode))[0]
                print (222)
```

This hangs after printing 111.

[EDIT1]

I've solved my problem by using an executable (translated from C++) as a filter, rather than a .bat or a .py file. This doesn't generate any console echo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string buffer;
    getline (cin, buffer, '\f');
    transform (buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), buffer.begin(), ::toupper);
    cout << buffer;
}
```

The input data has to end on a termination char, in this case I've used '\f':

```
'''
<div id="StudentContainer">
    {self.props.students.map((s) => (
        <StudentTile student={s}  key={s.searchval}  />
    ))}
</div>
\f'''
```

Comment: have you tried `subprocess.check_output()` instead of `Popen`?

Comment: No, I haven't. How do I pipe in the contents of variable `sourceCode` in that case?

Comment: Are you sure that the subprocess module is correctly handled by Transcript? AFAIK, Transcrypt aims at converting Python source to JavaScript to have it executed in a browser. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: The code doesn't depend on Transcrypt. The same problem happens if it's stand alone code. What I am trying to achieve is to lauch a subprocess, send a string to it, let the subprocess transform the string into something else and then assign the result to a variable. To prevent misunderstanding, I am not using Transcrypt itself to compile this code, the code is an enhancement of Transcrypt to allow external source processing, e.g. of JSX.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge Like this:`x = check_output('echo "4*25"', shell=True).decode().strip()`
`print(x)`
`y = check_output(f'echo "{x}" | bc', shell=True).decode().strip()`
`print(y)`

Comment: I've solved my problem by using an executable (translated from C++) as a filter, rather than a .bat or a .py file. This doesn't generate any console echo.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use communicate() to get output.

```
processes = [Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) for cmd in self.cmd_list]
for p in processes: p.wait()
for p in processes:
    output = p.communicate()[0]
    print output
```

Comment: I've tried to adapt my code accordingly (see [EDIT1]) but now it hangs. Seems there's still a problem.

Comment: Basically it is not hanging, `p.wait()` waits for process to complete execution. I needed things to work in synchronous manner that's why I use `wait()` but if you want to follow asynchronous way then you can remove `p.wait()` and I believe it will work for you without hanging.

Comment: I've now removed the `process.wait ()`, but it's still hanging.

Comment: Hanging as in, can you explain more

Comment: It prints 111 and then stops, so doesn't terminate